# Replace all but lowest values with 0 in grouped data in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for something that will allow me to replace all values that aren't the lowest value with 0 within a column for grouped data. What I want is the dif coulmn to be have the first(highest) value for group `time_bin 100`, and then the last(lowest) value for `time_bin 100` and 0s filling everything in between. Then repeated again for `time_bin 200`.

I have tried converting dif to a factor and using the code below, which returns the values I want, however I need the data to not be grouped and the min values to be in the same position that they are in the data provided and 0s everywhere else as there are further sums to be passed later which require it.

```
df%>% group_by(time_bin)%>%
slice(which.min(dif)


df <- structure(list(time_bin = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, NA), dif = c(99.05947825, 
98.1851055, 97.34940775, 96.524911, 95.68414125, 94.7996245, 
93.84388675, 92.789454, 91.60885225, 90.2746075, 88.75924575, 
87.035293, 85.07527525, 82.8517185, 80.33714875, 77.504092, 74.32507425, 
70.7726215, 66.81925975, 62.437515, 57.59991325, 52.2789805, 
46.44724275, 38.02773369375, 21.66041119375, 0.402574193749999, 
74.56978909375, 44.45892869375, 10.34817219375, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` to `group_by(time_bin)`, then `mutate(dif)` based on a `case_when()`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(time_bin) %>%
  mutate(dif = case_when(dif != max(dif) & dif != min(dif) ~ 0,
                         TRUE ~ dif))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answer, but this is giving me the highest and lowest value rather than just the lowest.

Comment: In your question, the first sentence was "to replace all values that aren't either the **highest or the lowest** value with 0", so I assumed you wanted to keep the highest also. All you need to do is adjust the first condition in the `case_when` to `dif != min(dif) ~ 0`.

Comment: Ah apologies, I realised half way through writing the question that I only needed the highest. Thanks.